# Conditions for friendship paradox variant

Tags: graph-theory

The [friendship paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friendship_paradox) is sometimes summarised as stating that:

1. **Most people have fewer friends than most of their friends.**

However, the mathematical explanation provided usually shows something different: namely, that

2. **The average number of friends that a typical person has is less than the average number that a typical friend has.**

In other words, the average degree of a randomly selected vertex in an undirected graph is less than the average degree of a randomly selected endpoint of a randomly selected edge.

Furthermore, the following variation of the paradox is *not* always true:

3. **Most people have fewer friends than their friends have on average.**

This can be seen by removing one edge from the complete graph $K_5$: 3 out of 5 people then have more friends (4) than their friends do on average (3.5). Note however, that statement 1 is still true for this graph (assuming less-than-or-equals definitions of 'most' and 'fewer') as those 3 don't actually have more friends than half of their friends.

**Is statement 1 always true? If not, under what conditions does it hold?**

***Clarification***: statement 1 asserts that for an arbitrary finite undirected graph, fewer than half of the vertices are popular, where a vertex is popular iff it has a greater degree than over half of its neighbours.